# Black box testing javascript MVC web applications

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, javascript

I want to test a web application that has been built using the [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) framework.

Currently I have used a few tools for crawling and testing without any luck. When crawling the website they can only find the MVC js files, and not the dynamically build pages. 
What I ideally need is a tool that is able to parse the javascript in order to build the pages, and test them from there.

Are there any tools available that focus on AJAX intensive web applications?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that there are a few solutions to this issue. First is to use [Burpsuite](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/) to index the website. It will function as a proxy and will register all calls made to the website, while you are browsing the website through your web-browser.
This proxy technique can be also applied to other pentesting tools, if supported.

The next step would be to write your own interface to these calls and use the pentest tool from there.

Comment: Incidentally, the OWASP Project has a similar tool called WebScarab which may be used for similar purposes, and has a nice plugin architecture (as does Burp)